# Pinch to Zoom on Map Zooms whole page issue with Cordova Windows 10 Hosted App?

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I have created Windows 10 Cordova Hosted App and one of major functionality of my App is a Map. But I am facing one of major issue and Issue is, when I am trying pinch to Zoom Map, Zooms whole page. The map zoom control are working fine for me and Mouse Zoom control also working fine.

Comment: Could you please post some codes to show what you have currently tried. And maybe some screenshot to show what unexpected behavior have you met.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Thank you for your quick response. I found the solution of this issue, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of this issue. Edge is the default browser for Windows 10. But, Edge browser does not know the "-ms-touch-action" but knows "touch-action". So adding of "touch-action: none" in my CSS file solved the issue.

Below is my Code

Map.html file

`<div class="map-container">
</div>`

Css file

```
.map-container {
      overflow: hidden;
      touch-action:none; //
     -ms-touch-action: none;
}
```

IE 11 knows both but Edge just the one.